# Increasing all font sizes in ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

I'm looking for the ggvis equivalent of this ggplot2 function call: `theme(text=element_text(size=20))`

Let's take a simple graph made with ggvis:

```
mtcars %>% 
  add_rownames() %>% 
  ggvis(~mpg, ~disp, fill = ~vs) %>% 
  layer_text(text := ~rowname)
```

[image]

**There are font sizes for axis titles, tick labels, the text layer, the legend title, and the legend tick labels**. In the SVG, all of these font sizes are set in the element:

Here, for example, is one of the labels in the legend:

```
<text x="3" y="36" text-anchor="start" dy=".9em" style="font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10px; line-height: normal; font-family: sans-serif; fill: #000000; opacity: 1;">0.0</text>
```

Notice `font-size: 10px;`. This prevents me from modifying the font size via CSS in the page where the svg will be embedded.

Is there any global way of stripping ALL fontSizes from the elements, so I can use CSS? Or is there a way to increase all fontSizes via ggvis?

Comment: Apparently this is not yet possible - https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/640861832371044354